# need way to reference equations

Tags: equations

I would like to use something, maybe a. b. or (1) (2) to show which equation correlates with which part of the table. Also it will be nice to be able to reference the various models in my discussion. I looked at another thread but their tip of using /label{} didn't work.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\setcellgapes{2pt}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\raggedbottom
\usepackage{amsmath,geometry}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{upquote}
\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2} % Times Roman math font

\begin{document}

$\text{CEO Salary} = 
  \beta_0 + 
  \beta_1\,\text{return} + 
  \beta_2\,\text{bonus} + 
  \beta_3\,\text{stock awards} + 
  \beta_4\,\text{option awards} +
  \beta_5\,\text{other compensation} 
  \beta_6\,\text{age} +
  \beta_7\,\text{age sq} +
  \beta_8\,\text{male} +
  \beta_9\,\text{industry} +
  \beta_{10}\,\text{volume} $ \label{eqn:first}

  $\text{Total Compensation} = 
  \beta_0 + 
  \beta_1\,\text{return} + 
  \beta_2\,\text{age} + 
  \beta_3\,\text{male} + 
  \beta_4\,\text{interaction term?} +
  \beta_5\,\text{industry} 
  \beta_6\,\text{volume} +
  \beta_7\,\text{age sq} +
  \beta_8\,\text{male} +
  \beta_9\,\text{industry} +
  \beta_{10}\,\text{volume} $ \label{eqn:second} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Label does work, but only you write the equations in appropriate environment such as `equation`, `align` etc.

Answer (score 3):

Combining equation and array environments maybe give you an answer:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\setcellgapes{2pt}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\raggedbottom
\usepackage{amsmath,geometry}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{upquote}
\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2} % Times Roman math font

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eqn:first}
\begin{array}{rl}
&\text{CEO Salary} \\
=&\beta_0 + 
\beta_1\,\text{return}+
\beta_2\,\text{bonus}\\ 
& +\beta_3\,\text{stock awards}\\ 
& +\beta_4\,\text{option awards} \\
& +\beta_5\,\text{other compensation}\beta_6\,\text{age} \\
& +\beta_7\,\text{age sq} 
+\beta_8\,\text{male} \\
& +\beta_9\,\text{industry} 
+\beta_{10}\,\text{volume} 
\end{array}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{eqn:second}
\begin{array}{rl}
&\text{Total Compensation}\\
=&
\beta_0 + 
\beta_1\,\text{return}\\ 
& +\beta_2\,\text{age} 
+\beta_3\,\text{male} \\
& +\beta_4\,\text{interaction term?}\\
& +\beta_5\,\text{industry} 
\beta_6\,\text{volume}\\
& +\beta_7\,\text{age sq}
+\beta_8\,\text{male}\\
& +\beta_9\,\text{industry}
+\beta_{10}\,\text{volume}
\end{array}
\end{equation} 

\end{document}
```

And they act as

[image]

Comment: You should add `{}` in front of the `+` at the beginning of rows, for a correct spacing.

Comment: @Bernard it's unnecessary in the `array` environment.

Comment: Well, the spacing is not the same as in the first rows.

Comment: @Bernard It has nothing to do with `{}`. It is related to `arraysep`!

Comment: But in these rows, there's nothing in the first column?!

Comment: @Bernard Yes, indeed so!